# Запуск sh скрипта и получениее его PID

Tags: c, unix, shell

Возникла необходимость получить PID запускаемого скрипта, для того, чтобы можно было убить этот процесс при закрытии основной программы.

Но `system()` не возвращает PID.

Есть ли какое-нибудь решение данной проблемы?

Comment: сначала fork() потом в дочернем процессе exec()

Comment: А смысл? Если процесс запускается при помощи `system()`, ЕМНИП, он и будет завершён при прибитии запускающей программы.

Comment: С system() что-то мне кажется не получится. Почему именно system()? С popen() например можно попробовать.

Comment: @0xbb Вам не кажется, так и есть в самом деле. Зачем нужен pid процесса, который **уже закончился**? (`system()` возвращает статус завершения, т.е. когда она возвращает управление в caller, то все уже произошло)  / Автор, опишите, что вам надо на самом деле.

Comment: @avp подозреваю автор вызывает скрипты с &

Comment: @0xdb, м.б... Тогда надо формировать что-то в духе  `ls a* >/dev/null &  echo last pid $!` и вызывать `popen`

Comment: @avp С popen() я что-то, признюсь, поспешил. Нужен только пид, а  не весь выход от скрипта. Возможно конечно, но можно проще.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С `system()`, кроме статуса завершения, ничего больше не получить. Надо `system()` заменить на свою функцию. Это только прототип, а не полностью рабочая функция. Конкретная реализация завсит от конкретных требований.

```
pid_t execute(char **argv)
{
     pid_t  pid;
     int    status;

     if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
         printf("ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     else if (pid == 0) { /* child process */
          if (execvp(*argv, argv) < 0) {
              printf("ERROR: exec failed\n");
              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }
     }
     else { /* parent */
         return pid);
     }
}
```

Что ешё не хватает:
Каждый возвращаемый PID надо собирать куда-нибудь в массив, и когда то их надо с `waitpid()` опрашивать, иначе процессов-сирот (*orphan process*) насобирается столько, что свободные PID закончатся и система подвиснет:

```
void gather_child(int sig)
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
    if (pid > 0) { /* remove pid from the list */ }
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGCHLD, gather_child);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Вряд ли  PID sh -c ему поможет, если он будет запускать скрипт в фоне (шелл завершится, а родителем станет /sbin/upstart --user)

Comment: @avp Точно. Когда-то делал, но уже забыл как. Надо в кодах порыть. Пока sh -c  уберу. Спасибо за конструктивное замечание.

Comment: @avp А зачем при таком решении в фоне запускать? Это примерно тоже что и system() делает, только без wait().

Comment: Это верно. На самом деле мы просто не знаем, что и как хочет запускать ТС. Может ему надо еще и от управляющего терминала отсоединяться и создавать новую группу процессов. Но поскольку он пишет "чтобы можно было убить этот процесс при закрытии основной программы", то может можно обойтись  просто `killpg()`